# Chrome cancels URL_REQUEST after exactly 3 seconds

Tags: google-chrome, reload, stalled

Ok, so this is a weird one.

I am working on a php script that does a lot of work when requested (image processing). So this is not unusual it issues a response in 10 seconds, up to 30 seconds sometimes : it's a long script, and this is important for the next part.

While logging the image processing code, I noticed that processes that should be called only once were called twice.

The reason : Chrome is cancelling the first request after 3s, then requests the same URL again.

[image: URL cancel sequence]

The sequence is always the same.

1. URL requested
2. Cancel after 3 seconds sharp
3. Auto-reload with http scheme
4. 307 due to HSTS on our server
5. URL requested again with https
6. This one loads correctly

The cancelled request is shown as Stalled in "Timing" tab.

[image: Stalled URL request]

This is only happening in Chrome (92.0.4515.107 for me). I don't see this behavior in Firefox.

Now how can one reproduce this witchcraft ? Easy, I can reproduce on 2 different servers on 2 different providers (GCE, and OVH) and it has a weird link **with the duration of the initial request to this URL**.

1. Create a new php script on your webserver only containing

   `<?php sleep(10); echo 'Done'; ?>`
2. Call your script URL in Chrome
3. **The first call will succeed**
4. But all the next calls will certainly trigger "the sequence"

By checking on Chrome logs, I came to think this has a link with HTTP2_SESSION

```
t=235805 [st=   5]     +HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST  [dt=1]
t=235806 [st=   6]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_HTTP2_SEND_REQUEST_HEADERS
                          --> :method: GET
                              :authority: my.server.com
                              :scheme: https
                              :path: /admin/ot/test1.php
                              pragma: no-cache
                              cache-control: no-cache
                              authorization: [38 bytes were stripped]
                              sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"
                              sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
                              upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
                              user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36
                              accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
                              sec-fetch-site: none
                              sec-fetch-mode: navigate
                              sec-fetch-user: ?1
                              sec-fetch-dest: document
                              accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
                              accept-language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
                              cookie: [409 bytes were stripped]
t=235806 [st=   6]     -HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST
t=235806 [st=   6]     +HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_HEADERS  [dt=3012]
t=238818 [st=3018]        CANCELLED
t=238818 [st=3018] -REQUEST_ALIVE
```

On the URL_REQUEST above, we don't learn much. We just see "CANCELLED" after 3s.

But the HTTP2_SESSION shows a strange error :

```
27185: HTTP2_SESSION
my.server.com:443 (DIRECT)
Start Time: 2021-07-22 17:13:09.460

t=222444 [st=    0] +HTTP2_SESSION  [dt=28616+]
                     --> host = "my.server.com:443"
                     --> proxy = "DIRECT"
t=222444 [st=    0]    HTTP2_SESSION_INITIALIZED
                       --> protocol = "h2"
                       --> source_dependency = 27181 (SOCKET)
t=222445 [st=    1]    HTTP2_SESSION_SEND_SETTINGS
                       --> settings = ["[id:1 (SETTINGS_HEADER_TABLE_SIZE) value:65536]","[id:3 (SETTINGS_MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS) value:1000]","[id:4 (SETTINGS_INITIAL_WINDOW_SIZE) value:6291456]","[id:6 (SETTINGS_MAX_HEADER_LIST_SIZE) value:262144]"]
t=222445 [st=    1]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                       --> delta = 15663105
                       --> window_size = 15728640
t=222445 [st=    1]    HTTP2_SESSION_SEND_WINDOW_UPDATE
                       --> delta = 15663105
                       --> stream_id = 0
t=222446 [st=    2]    HTTP2_SESSION_SEND_HEADERS
                       --> exclusive = true
                       --> fin = true
                       --> has_priority = true
                       --> :method: GET
                           :authority: my.server.com
                           :scheme: https
                           :path: /admin/ot/test1.php
                           pragma: no-cache
                           cache-control: no-cache
                           authorization: [38 bytes were stripped]
                           sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"
                           sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
                           upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
                           user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36
                           accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
                           sec-fetch-site: none
                           sec-fetch-mode: navigate
                           sec-fetch-user: ?1
                           sec-fetch-dest: document
                           accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
                           accept-language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
                           cookie: [409 bytes were stripped]
                       --> parent_stream_id = 0
                       --> source_dependency = 27179 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
                       --> stream_id = 1
                       --> weight = 256
t=222471 [st=   27]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_SETTINGS
t=222471 [st=   27]    HTTP2_SESSION_SEND_SETTINGS_ACK
t=222471 [st=   27]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_SETTING
                       --> id = "3 (SETTINGS_MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS)"
                       --> value = 100
t=222471 [st=   27]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_STREAMS_SEND_WINDOW_SIZE
                       --> delta_window_size = 983041
t=222471 [st=   27]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_SETTING
                       --> id = "4 (SETTINGS_INITIAL_WINDOW_SIZE)"
                       --> value = 1048576
t=222471 [st=   27]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_SETTING
                       --> id = "6 (SETTINGS_MAX_HEADER_LIST_SIZE)"
                       --> value = 65536
t=222471 [st=   27]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_WINDOW_UPDATE
                       --> delta = 983041
                       --> stream_id = 0
t=222471 [st=   27]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_SEND_WINDOW
                       --> delta = 983041
                       --> window_size = 1048576
t=222471 [st=   27]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_SETTINGS_ACK
t=232550 [st=10106]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_HEADERS
                       --> fin = false
                       --> :status: 200
                           date: Thu, 22 Jul 2021 15:13:09 GMT
                           vary: Accept-Encoding
                           content-encoding: gzip
                           strict-transport-security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
                           x-ua-compatible: IE=Edge
                           x-frame-options: sameorigin
                           x-content-type-options: nosniff
                           x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
                           content-length: 24
                           content-type: text/html; charset=CP1252
                           cache-control: 
                           age: 0
                           x-cache: NOT CACHABLE
                           accept-ranges: bytes
                           via: 1.1 google
                           alt-svc: clear
                       --> stream_id = 1
t=232550 [st=10106]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                       --> delta = -1
                       --> window_size = 15728639
t=232550 [st=10106]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                       --> delta = 1
                       --> window_size = 15728640
t=232550 [st=10106]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_DATA
                       --> fin = false
                       --> size = 24
                       --> stream_id = 1
t=232550 [st=10106]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                       --> delta = -24
                       --> window_size = 15728616
t=232550 [st=10106]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                       --> delta = -110
                       --> window_size = 15728506
t=232550 [st=10106]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                       --> delta = 110
                       --> window_size = 15728616
t=232550 [st=10106]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                       --> delta = -1
                       --> window_size = 15728615
t=232550 [st=10106]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                       --> delta = 1
                       --> window_size = 15728616
t=232550 [st=10106]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                       --> delta = -71
                       --> window_size = 15728545
t=232551 [st=10107]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                       --> delta = 71
                       --> window_size = 15728616
t=232551 [st=10107]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_DATA
                       --> fin = true
                       --> size = 0
                       --> stream_id = 1
t=232551 [st=10107]    HTTP2_SESSION_PING
                       --> is_ack = false
                       --> type = "received"
                       --> unique_id = 0
t=232551 [st=10107]    HTTP2_SESSION_PING
                       --> is_ack = true
                       --> type = "sent"
                       --> unique_id = 0
t=232552 [st=10108]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                       --> delta = 24
                       --> window_size = 15728640
t=235806 [st=13362]    HTTP2_SESSION_SEND_HEADERS
                       --> exclusive = true
                       --> fin = true
                       --> has_priority = true
                       --> :method: GET
                           :authority: my.server.com
                           :scheme: https
                           :path: /admin/ot/test1.php
                           pragma: no-cache
                           cache-control: no-cache
                           authorization: [38 bytes were stripped]
                           sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"
                           sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
                           upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
                           user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36
                           accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
                           sec-fetch-site: none
                           sec-fetch-mode: navigate
                           sec-fetch-user: ?1
                           sec-fetch-dest: document
                           accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
                           accept-language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
                           cookie: [409 bytes were stripped]
                       --> parent_stream_id = 0
                       --> source_dependency = 27212 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
                       --> stream_id = 3
                       --> weight = 256
t=238818 [st=16374]    HTTP2_SESSION_SEND_RST_STREAM
                       --> description = ""
                       --> error_code = "8 (CANCEL)"
                       --> stream_id = 3
t=238846 [st=16402]    HTTP2_SESSION_SEND_HEADERS
                       --> exclusive = true
                       --> fin = true
                       --> has_priority = true
                       --> :method: GET
                           :authority: my.server.com
                           :scheme: https
                           :path: /admin/ot/test1.php
                           pragma: no-cache
                           cache-control: no-cache
                           authorization: [38 bytes were stripped]
                           upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
                           user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36
                           accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
                           sec-fetch-site: none
                           sec-fetch-mode: navigate
                           sec-fetch-user: ?1
                           sec-fetch-dest: document
                           sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"
                           sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
                           accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
                           accept-language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
                           cookie: [409 bytes were stripped]
                       --> parent_stream_id = 0
                       --> source_dependency = 27225 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
                       --> stream_id = 5
                       --> weight = 256
t=249924 [st=27480]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_HEADERS
                       --> fin = false
                       --> :status: 200
                           date: Thu, 22 Jul 2021 15:13:25 GMT
                           vary: Accept-Encoding
                           content-encoding: gzip
                           strict-transport-security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
                           x-ua-compatible: IE=Edge
                           x-frame-options: sameorigin
                           x-content-type-options: nosniff
                           x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
                           content-length: 24
                           content-type: text/html; charset=CP1252
                           cache-control: 
                           age: 0
                           x-cache: NOT CACHABLE
                           accept-ranges: bytes
                           via: 1.1 google
                           alt-svc: clear
                       --> stream_id = 5
t=249924 [st=27480]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                       --> delta = -1
                       --> window_size = 15728639
t=249924 [st=27480]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                       --> delta = 1
                       --> window_size = 15728640
t=249924 [st=27480]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_DATA
                       --> fin = false
                       --> size = 24
                       --> stream_id = 5
t=249924 [st=27480]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                       --> delta = -24
                       --> window_size = 15728616
t=249925 [st=27481]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                       --> delta = -94
                       --> window_size = 15728522
t=249925 [st=27481]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                       --> delta = 94
                       --> window_size = 15728616
t=249925 [st=27481]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                       --> delta = -1
                       --> window_size = 15728615
t=249925 [st=27481]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                       --> delta = 1
                       --> window_size = 15728616
t=249925 [st=27481]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                       --> delta = -104
                       --> window_size = 15728512
t=249925 [st=27481]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                       --> delta = 104
                       --> window_size = 15728616
t=249925 [st=27481]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_DATA
                       --> fin = true
                       --> size = 0
                       --> stream_id = 5
t=249925 [st=27481]    HTTP2_SESSION_PING
                       --> is_ack = false
                       --> type = "received"
                       --> unique_id = 2
t=249925 [st=27481]    HTTP2_SESSION_PING
                       --> is_ack = true
                       --> type = "sent"
                       --> unique_id = 2
t=249927 [st=27483]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                       --> delta = 24
                       --> window_size = 15728640
```

Walkthrough :

- Initial request (the one that worked) starts at st=0, ends at st=10106 (10 seconds of sleep)
- The second request (the one that gets automatically cancelled) starts at st=13362, ends at st=16374 (3s later) with this

```
t=238818 [st=16374]    HTTP2_SESSION_SEND_RST_STREAM
                       --> description = ""
                       --> error_code = "8 (CANCEL)"
                       --> stream_id = 3
```

- Then the request gets reloaded at st=16402, and finally gets back at st=27480 with its 10s sleep delay

I honestly don't know what to do with this. This can be reproduced easily but I can't figure out why it happens.

Chrome is largely used in my company for our internal tools, so I'm bugged it reloads heavy processing URL 2 times in a row for mysterious reasons.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

OH, and I did disable every extensions I have. It does not help. I don't see any mention to any extension intervention in Chrome logs anyway.

Comment: Glad to find this post! Have you filed a bug report with Chrome? I JUST updated Chrome to v 93.0.4577.82 and I can still replicate this both with the example domain below and with my own domain where the problem first occurred.

Comment: Bug report filed: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1251065

Comment: Amazing! Same problem here! It is a nightmare. Can't workaround it!

Comment: @fast-reflexes the link doesn't work

Comment: It's because it's a security issue, only poster and chromium team can see but it is confirmed and they will fix it

Comment: Now the thread is unlocked since it was 14 weeks since the fix was pushed to the newest version of Chrome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this problem can be reproduced on any domain which responses with longer than 3s delay and with any technology at the server side. I suppose this is a chrome issue. I reproduced it with ASP.net MVC and AWS Beanstalk hosting. I also reproduced it differently on https://example.com/ when you throttle connection to get slower response times.

To reproduce it (on Chrome Version 92.0.4515.159 (Official Build) (64-bit)):

1. Open Dev Tools and add Very Slow Network Throttling Profile as follows [image: Network Throttling Profiles]
2. go to url by pasting: https://example.com/ -> this should work
3. refresh page by pressing F5 -> this should work as well
4. now, **very important**, just click the address bar twice so you can see:
   [image: URL] and then press enter. Now chrome behaves differently and first it tries the https url and if there is no response within 3s it redirects to http. The cancelled request is the one I am talking about.
   [image: Network requests]

Maybe this will help sb resolving the issue.

Comment: I can still reproduce this in newest Chrome (93.0.4577.82). If I set the latency to 4000 ms and 1000 kb up and down, I see this downgrade. VERY odd to see downgrades from https to http like this in a well-known browser in times of HSTS and other attempts to avoid http connections. Behaviour not present in Firefox. Wonder if it's a bug or a feature?

Comment: The weirdest thing ever, and this thing happens already for a very long time!

Comment: What's more weird is that it reproduces for some accounts, and for other it doesn't. On same machine.

Answer (score 1):

For the same problem, I didn't find such a problem when I used Firefox. At first, I suspected that it was a server-side configuration problem. Later, I found that the problem remained after changing the environment. Finally, it was located on the browser side, but I don't know what the specific reason is

Comment: If you find the cause of the problem, please let me know

Comment: After upgrading to version 93, the problem no longer appears. I think this problem should be a bug in Google version 92

Comment: Still appears for me in Chrome 93.0.4577.82

Comment: For me still appears in chrome 94

Comment: Sorry, I found that this problem has not been solved, but after upgrading the version, the probability of the problem will be reduced

Answer (score 0):

If your server don't support https, please try to enter 'http://' to specify the protocol for each request. Otherwise Chrome tries https automatically. It takes 3 seconds, and then go http.